# Django. "python manage.py runserver <my-ip>:<port>" getting "resource (<my-ip>) is online but isn't responding to connection attempts." on chrome

Tags: django, google-chrome, server, backend

I can start django's development server using

```
$ python manage.py runserver <my-ip>:<port>
```

However, when I try to access the page in Chrome, it takes too long to open and shows an error. When I run the troubleshooter, I get the following response:

```
resource (<my-ip>) is online but isn't responding to connection attempts
```

I have tried the following:

1. ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
2. changing port to 80, 8080, 8000, etc.
3. removing adblockers
4. restarting everything
5. disabling firewall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try running:

```
python manage.py runserver 0:<port>
```

This will then allow you to go to `127.0.0.1:<port>` or `localhost:<port>` in your browser.

Whichever one you choose between `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`, you will need to add it inside your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` list.

Comment: Yes, the Django server works with those, but it is not accessible by other machines on my server. I want to use Django as backend and react native as frontend, the above 2 don't work while I try to use them in my react app.

Comment: [`manage.py runserver` is intended for development purpose only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#runserver). You should never use this for serving an actual production instance. Check out the [Deployment Howto](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/) for information on how to properly deploy your app.

Comment: You must be on the same network to access it from React using `runserver`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a "Hello world" view and try to fetch that one